# Followed Sites and Documents issues

Tags: newsfeed, mysites

I changed the host URL of the web application used for My sites.  Everything is working except for Followed sites and Followed Documents.

They are still retaining the old links - new link is `http://team` but the URL in Followed sites = `http://team.company.local`

Clicking Stop Following does nothing.  Clicking the site itself brings up a message saying:
We hit a snag

> This link doesn't work anymore, likely because the item was moved or
>   deleted. You might have luck searching for it and following it in its
>   new location.

I have found these logs from ULS when trying to click the Followed site or strying to Stop Following:

> FollowedContent.StopFollowing(http ://
>   team.company.local/sites/project11) : Local execution failed; Could
>   not stop following the item http ://
>   team.company.local/sites/project11: Exception: ItemDoesNotExist : Item
>   does not exist.
>
> Original error:
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.FollowedContentException:
>   ItemDoesNotExist : Item does not exist.
>
> Cannot find site lookup info for request Uri http ://
>   mysites.company.local/User Photos/Profile Pictures/derek_MThumb.jpg.

I have been looked at the Msft article about the `We Hit a snag` error and it is not the case in my environment. Database permissions for the web application pools are all ok.

I have restarted the whole farm to no avail.

Comment: How many users do you have? You can code a PowerShell block that fetches the User Profiles and for each user profile GetFollowed Content. Then trigger a Stop Follow event.

Comment: Hi, I can't find any Powershell commands relating to followed content?

Answer (score 1):

If you add `http://team.company.local` to your alternate access mappings, SP will probably replace it with the correct `http://team` url for you.

If that doesn't work, I would setup IIS and DNS to support both urls temporarly until you can get items to stop following.

If neither of those are acceptable, you should be able to use powershell or a console app or something to manage the followed content.  I believe you will be looking to use [SPSocialFollowingManger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.social.spsocialfollowingmanager.aspx)

Comment: Hi, I have http :// team.company.local as an internal but it doesn't make any difference with this issue.  If I type the http :// team.company.local link into IE it'll load fine.  The MSDN link you've posted looks really interesting but I'm not long into SharePoint so don;t know how to make use of the it.

Comment: If http://team.company.local works in IE, then you should be able to remove the follow.  Does that work now?

Comment: No, unfortunately not.  if I go to http :// team.company.local and click follow, it'll add http ://team to the sites which is good, but when I click Stop Following on the http :// team.company.local it removes http ://team?  It like ghost entries in the database.  feels like I need to remove the entries from the database directly.

Comment: Umm, interesting.  You might need to make team.company.local the default in the alternate access mappings, remove all of the followings and then change it back to teams.  Or remove them through the API using the spsocialfollowingmanager.

Comment: There looks to be an underlying issue.  I created a domain user, setup a mysite, browsed to http :// team and followed a site, but it added it as http :// team.company.local?  very strange........

Comment: Yea, i wonder if it is using the url from the default alternate access mapping