# Automatically unfollow deleted site collections?

Tags: 2013

If I delete a site collection my users are still following them.
How can I get all users to automatically unfollow sites that are/were deleted?

Comment: You could write a custom PowerShell script that (quote)@Alvmad: "fetches the User Profiles and for each user profile GetFollowed Content. Then trigger a Stop Follow event" (from http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/81009/17814). But this is not automatically, and I guess you need to know which sites are/were deleted. Maybe you can retrieve them and test urls from GetFollowed content. HTH

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `SPWebEventReceiver.WebDeleting` event receiver. In this you need to retrieve all user profiles and check if a user is following the site and then stop follwing that site. The main thing here is the `ActorType` needs to be `SPSocialActorType.Site`

```
SPSocialFollowingManager manager = new   
        SPSocialFollowingManager(userProfile);
SPSocialActorInfo actorInfo = new SPSocialActorInfo();
actorInfo.ContentUri = new Uri(web.Url);
actorInfo.AccountName = user.LoginName;
actorInfo.ActorType = SPSocialActorType.Site;
manager.StopFollowing(actorInfo);
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23271133/how-do-i-follow-site-in-sharepoint-2013-with-ssom