# Automation of Unfollowing Deleted Sites and Documents

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

Upon deletion of a site or document, I'd like the site/document to be deleted from everyone's "follow" list.  However, it appears that is not happening.  I've confirmed the "Activity Feed Timer Job" is functioning normally.

This is SP On Prem 2013

Answer (score 0):

You could create an event receiver to achieve it.

When the site is deleted, then it unfollows the site.

More references:

[How to UnFollow Site or Stop Following Sites Programmatically in SharePoint 2013 using client side (CSOM).](http://www.roelbagao.com/2017/03/22/how-to-unfollow-site-or-stop-following-sites-programmatically-in-sharepoint-2013-using-client-side-csom/)

[Creating Simple Event Receiver in SharePoint 2013.](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/5b1f04/creating-simple-event-receiver-in-sharepoint-2013/)

There is a similar post:

[Automatically unfollow deleted site collections?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/130743/automatically-unfollow-deleted-site-collections?rq=1)

Comment: shouldn't this be happening automatically?...there's nothing to follow once its deleted...and this is for ALL the users